# Помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: транскрипция

Нужно затранскрибировать текст.

*Память и знание прошлого наполняют мир, делают его интересным, значительным, одухотворенным. Если вы не видите за окружающим вас миром его прошлого, он для вас пуст. Вам скучно, вам тоскливо, и вы в  конечном счете одиноки, ибо и товарищи для вас – товарищи по-настоящему, когда вас связывает с ними какое-то общее прошлое: окончили школу, институт, либо работали вместе, а старики помнят с особенной нежностью тех, с кем воевали, пережили какие-то трудности.*

Answer (score 0):

Вот я что-то нашла, но не уверена что правильно.

Помогите!

па́м'ьт' и́ зна́н'ьjъ про́шлъвʌ /наполняют/ м'и́р, д'э́лъjут jиево́ иен'т'иер'э́сныэм, знʌчи́т'ьл'ныэм, /одухотворенным/. jэ́сл'ь вы́ н'э́ в'и́д'ьт'ь зъ ʌкружа́jуш'ːьм ва́с м'и́ръм jиево́ про́шлъвʌ, о́н дл'ь ва́с пу́ст. ва́м ску́шнʌ, ва́м тʌскл'и́вʌ, и́ вы́ ф‿кʌн'э́чнъм ш'ːо́т'ь /одиноки/, и́бʌ и́ тʌва́р'ьш'ːь дл'ь ва́с – тʌва́р'ьш'ːь пънъстʌjа́ш'ːьму, кʌгда́ ва́с св'а́зыэвъjьт с‿н'и́м'ь кʌко́jъ-тʌ о́пш'ːьjъ про́шлъjъ: /окончили/ шко́лу, иен'с'т'иету́т, л'и́бʌ рʌбо́тъл'ь вм'э́с'т'ь, а́ стър'иек'и́ по́мн'ьт с‿ʌсо́б'ьнːъj н'э́жнъс'т'jу т'э́х, с‿к'э́м въjиева́л'ь, п'э́р'ьжыэл'ь кʌк'и́jъ-тʌ тру́днъс'т'ь.

Answer (score 0):

па́м'ьт' и  зна́н'иiь про́шлъвъ нъпʌлн'аiут м'и́р, д'э́лъiут jиэво́ ин'т'ьр'э́сным, знʌч' и́т'ьл'ным, ъдухътвʌр'онːым. jиэ́сл'и вы́ н'иэ в'и́д'ит'ь зъ ъкружа́jуш'ːим вʌс‿м'и́ръм jиэво́ про́шлъвъ, о́н дл'ʌ‿ва́с пу́ст. ва́м ску́шнъ, ва́м тʌскл'и́въ, и́ вы́ ф‿кʌн'э́чнъм ш'ːо́т'ь ъд'инок'и, и́бъ и́ тʌва́р'иш'ːи дл'иэ‿ва́с – тʌва́р'иш'ːи пънъстʌjа́ш'ːьму, кʌгда́ ва́с св'а́зывъjут с‿н'и́м'и кʌко́iь-тъ о́пшːьjь про́шлъiь: ʌкон'ч'ил'и шко́лу, инст'иту́т, л'и́бъ рʌбо́тъл'и вм'э́с'т'ь, а́ стър'ик'и́ по́мн'ьт с‿ʌсо́б'ьнːъi н'э́жнъс'т'jу т'э́х, с‿к'э́м въjиэва́л'и, п'ьр'ьжыл'и кʌк'и́iь-тъ тру́днъс'т'и.

Татьяна, паузы расставьте сами вертикальными чертами, если у вас требуют.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: 1) вместо запятых знак / , вместо точки знак // ; 2) ин'т'иэр'э́сным - первая позиция перед ударным;3)ʌдухътвʌр'онːым - абсолютное начало -ослабленное а;4) jэ́сл'и;5)ʌкружа́jуш'ːьм - абс. начало; 6)ʌд'инок'и; 7)св'а́зывъjьт -( ет, а не ют);

Comment: Я думаю, что в ʌкружа́jуш'ːьм вместо редуцированного Ь в окончании всё -таки И (звук остаётся неизменным, хотя и в слабой позиции)

Comment: Верно, это я уже просмотрела, я плохо вижу, а сейчас усмотрела и предлог, значит, и не абсолютное начало, так что по этому слову - всё верно.